# テキストファイルを読み取ってmvコマンドを利用したい

Tags: linux, ubuntu

テキストファイル内に
aaa.JPG
bbb.JPG
ccc.JPG
・
・
・
とファイル名が羅列されていて、このテキストファイルを利用してここに載っているファイル名を全てあるフォルダから別のフォルダに移動させたいです。

mvコマンドでできそうな気がしますが、どのように記述するのでしょうか。

Comment: xargs と mv コマンドの `-t` オプションを組み合わせると良さそうです。 `cat files.lst | xargs mv -t /path/to/dest_dir` ただ、質問欄のファイルパスを見ますと、移動させるファイルがあるディレクトリに移動して実行する必要があります。

Answer (score 2):

具体的な内容がちょっと分からないので補完しつつ一般的な例を書きます。

`/tmp/spam/`がカレントディレクトリで、そこに例示したテキストファイル（`test.txt`とします）とaaa.JPG、bbb.JPG、……があり、`/tmp/eggs/`に移動したいものとします。このとき、

```
$ pwd
/tmp/spam/
$ cat test.txt | xargs -n 1 -I % mv % /tmp/eggs
```

と実行することで、テキストファイルの各行のファイルを移動先に移動させることが可能です。

Comment: UbuntuでGNU mvありますが、`-t` を使えます： `xargs -a test.txt mv -t /tmp/eggs` (`-t`で異動先は最初に指定できます）

Answer (score 1):

Bashやzshでは、`$(<ファイル名)`により、テキストファイルの内容をコマンドラインに展開できます。

```
$ mv $(<filelist.txt) /path/to/dest_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

`sh/bash`のfor文と組み合わせてならできそうです。

```
$ for f in 'cat filelist.txt`
> do
> mv $f DEST_DIR
> done
```